# Lazy loading for ManyToOne mapping not working in eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, lazy-loading

Address has many-to-one relationship with person like :

Person :

```
@Id 
    @Column(name="personid")
    private Long personId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;    

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="person",targetEntity=Address.class,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)      
    private List addressArray=new ArrayList<>();   
    public Person() {

    }
```

and Address :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="personId")
    private Person person;
```

I want to access person's firstname from the address object like "address.person.firstname" but it always eager load the person ?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by inverse entity?

In general, yes, LAZY is supported on any relationship type.
For ManyToOne you must ensure you use the EclipseLink agent to allow dynamic weaving (or JavaEE/Spring),
you can also use static weaving.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving

Comment: Thanx! for the answer, inverse entity means for eg. Person has One to Many relation with Address so when querying inversely i.e for Address it fetches the person also.

Comment: I didn't get meaning of eclipselink agent? Iam using eclipselink.jar as provider.How do I enable dynamic weaving in eclipselink.